# XML Re-deserialization Error

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization

my application deserializes data from XML files whenever it opens. The deserialization works fine the first time the application loads, but when I try to reopen the program, I get the following error:

```
2/27/2014 6:27:30 PM  : Error: There is an error in XML document (9, 6).. Stacktrace:    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events) at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle) at XMLInterface.XMLInterface.Deserialize(String CallingSub, String LocalFileURI) in C:\AzTech\Satellite\Code Repository\trunk\Ribbon\XMLInterface\Code\XMLInterface.vb:line 66
```

Also, the application is part of an add-in solution so that when the app closes, the add-in is still running. If I close the add-in and rerun it, serialization works fine; it's only after I close and reopen the app on its own that the error occurs.

Here's my code:

```
        Dim ser As New XmlSerializer(ElementsLocal.GetType)
        Dim objStreamReader As New StreamReader(LocalFileURI)
        ElementsLocal = ser.Deserialize(objStreamReader)
        objStreamReader.Close()
        objStreamReader.Dispose()
        ser = Nothing
        GC.Collect()
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Do I need to release the file in some way? I assume that once the deserialization sub exits that the file would be released, but is that not the case?

**EDIT:**
The file is accessed by these processes as well (not sure if this would affect the situation):

```
    For Each Name As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(My.Settings.savePath)
        Dim cBox As New ComboBoxItem
        cBox.Content = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Name)
        cBox.Style = TryFindResource("blackComboBoxItem")
        cmbBxQBDNames.Items.Add(cBox)
    Next
```

**EDIT 2:**
Wrapping the code, as suggested, did not work either:

```
        Dim ser As New XmlSerializer(ElementsLocal.GetType)
        Using fs As FileStream = New FileStream(LocalFileURI, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
            Using objStreamReader As New StreamReader(fs)
                ElementsLocal = ser.Deserialize(objStreamReader)
            End Using
        End Using
        ser = Nothing
```

Comment: Having the whole error would be helpful, not just the stack trace.

Comment: I put in the whole error message earlier, but it was edited out by others.

Comment: It looks like a stack trace dump to a log file. I am referring to the whole error that tells you what went wrong and where (we have that part already).

Comment: The only thing that's missing I believe is: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: That tells me a whole lot more than the stack trace. Without knowing the line numbers, I am gonna guess that line 66 is the `Dim objStreamReader ...` line. If that is the case, you haven't initialized or set the value of LocalFileURI.  Knowing which of the include lines of code are what line number helps to debug.

Comment: ElementsLocal = ser.Deserialize(objStreamReader) is line 66, which doesn't cause any problem the first time I deserialize. Should I not dispose of the StreamReader? or not close it?

Comment: I am thinking that you might want to open the file using the StreamReader where the file is opened only for reading.

Comment: I don't quite follow - the Deserializer accepts a StreamReader object, which I've initialized in the line before it.

Comment: What is the declaration and assignment of the LocalFileURI?

Comment: It's a string parameter that get's passed to the function. I've verified that it has a value each time:
Public Function Deserialize(Optional ByVal CallingSub As String = Nothing, Optional ByVal LocalFileURI As String = Nothing)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you open the file using StreamReader, it locks the file from being used by other processes. This includes your application when you start a second instance and the first isn't fully out of memory.  Try this code:

```
Dim ser As New XmlSerializer(ElementsLocal.GetType)
Using fs As FileStream = New FileStream(LocalFileURI, _
                                        FileMode.Open, _
                                        FileAccess.Read, _
                                        FileShare.ReadWrite)
    Using objStreamReader As New StreamReader(fs)
        ElementsLocal = ser.Deserialize(objStreamReader)
    End Using
End Using
ser = Nothing
GC.Collect()
```

The Using statements define an object that you want to clean up without fail. At the `End Using` line, the compiler will `Dispose` of the object you created in the `Using` line (which will also close it for you). When you are working with files, network streams, or other things that should really only have one thing at a time working on them, the `Using` statement is a good choice.

The `FileStream` object gives you a way to open a file with different access levels to minimize (or maximize) interference with other processes. You only want to open an existing file, not create or append - `FileMode`. You don't need to do anything with this file, except read its contents - `FileAccess`. You want to minimize issues with other processes that may need access to the file - `FileShare`.

Comment: This solution seemed promising, but it did not fix the error - I still get an "Object Reference..." message.

Comment: Is some other part of your code opening the same file? If so, you will need to do something similar to prevent file locking issues.

Comment: The only other code I've found that accesses the file in some way I've added as an edit. Would those processes affect this situation?

Comment: It definitely can if you are opening the file using `StreamReader` like you did above.

Comment: Still no luck - I replaced the code that calls the files with code that gives a hardcoded name to the combobox item.

Comment: Did you wrap the filestreams like I show in the example above?

Comment: There must be some other place in your code where the file is being opened or processed in some other way that is locking the file. I would look for any references to the file at all and see if they open the file for any reason.